# Get record count of each day of last week. if no record found in particular date then i want 0 as record

Tags: mysql

**My sale Table**

```
ID amount  created_at
48  10     2018-10-15 10:57:24
49  20     2018-10-16 10:58:14
50  25     2018-10-22 14:07:31
51  24     2018-10-24 12:13:15
52  36     2018-10-24 12:13:21
53  40     2018-10-30 09:46:37
54  40     2018-10-28 09:46:37
55  40     2018-11-1 09:46:37
56  40     2018-11-2 09:46:37
57  40     2018-11-2 09:46:37
58  40     2018-11-2 09:46:37
59  40     2018-11-2 09:46:37
60  40     2018-11-2 09:46:37
```

**My qyery**

```
SELECT Date(created_at),
       Count(*)
FROM   sale
WHERE  Date(created_at) BETWEEN ( Now() - INTERVAL 7 day ) AND Now()
GROUP  BY Date(created_at)
```

**My result**

```
date(created_at)       count
2018-10-28 12:13:15    1
2018-10-1 09:46:37     1
2018-10-2 09:46:37     5
```

Suppose Week Start from 2018-10-28 and i need result like below if there is no record of particular day then it will 0.

```
day count
mon 1
tue 0
wed 0  
thu 1
fri 5
sat 0
sun 0
```

Comment: What if `Now()` is in the middle of the week ? Your "7-day-week" can be from Thursday to Wednesday ?

Comment: No. week start from monday to sunday always.

Comment: By the way, 28 October 2018 is Sunday, not Monday. Do check the posted answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Firstly, you can create a Master Table representing all the *Abbreviated Weekday name(s)*.
- Now, we can use [`Date_format()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) function with `%a` specifier to get the *abbreviated weekday name* for a particular `created_at` date. We can use this as our `Left Join` condition.
- `Left Join` allows us to consider all the Weekdays, even if there is no matching `created_at` for a particular day.
- `Count(*)` will not work here, as it counts all the rows in a group. However, we don't want to count the rows where there is no matching rows. So, we use `Count(created_at)`, as it will ignore the `null` values.
- Finally, query is made [sargable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/799584/2469308) by removing `Date()` function usage in the `Where` clause.

You will need to use a master table for week days.

**Query:**

```
SELECT week_table.day_order, 
       week_table.wkday AS `day`, 
       Count(created_at) AS `count` 
FROM   
(
 SELECT 'Mon' AS wkday, 1 AS day_order UNION ALL
 SELECT 'Tue', 2 UNION ALL
 SELECT 'Wed', 3 UNION ALL
 SELECT 'Thu', 4 UNION ALL
 SELECT 'Fri', 5 UNION ALL
 SELECT 'Sat', 6 UNION ALL
 SELECT 'Sun', 7
) AS week_table 
LEFT JOIN sale AS s 
  ON DATE_FORMAT(created_at, '%a') = week_table.wkday AND 
     created_at >= ( CURDATE() - INTERVAL 7 day ) AND 
     created_at <  ( CURDATE() + INTERVAL 1 day )
GROUP BY week_table.day_order, week_table.wkday 
ORDER BY week_table.day_order;
```

**Result**

```
| day_order | day | count |
| --------- | --- | ----- |
| 1         | Mon | 0     |
| 2         | Tue | 1     |
| 3         | Wed | 0     |
| 4         | Thu | 1     |
| 5         | Fri | 5     |
| 6         | Sat | 0     |
| 7         | Sun | 1     |
```

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/eakZ1rPk2LdjH3FjRMJ2aU/0)

Comment: how to print date also?

Comment: @DhruvRaval you can add it to the select clause and group By clause

Comment: @DhruvRaval check this fiddle: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/eakZ1rPk2LdjH3FjRMJ2aU/1

Comment: and how to get second last week data ?

Comment: need to change interval - 7 to 14 ?

Comment: @DhruvRaval yes

Comment: created_at >= ( CURDATE() - INTERVAL 14 day ) AND 
     created_at <=  ( CURDATE() - INTERVAL 7 day )   Is this Correct ?